# How to get the number of objects in an array? Mongoose

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

I have an array with objects how to get the number of objects in it?

**Array example:**

```json
{
   "users":[
      {
         "uid":9,
         "special":7,
         "coins":15000,
         "messages":85
      },
      {
         "uid":11,
         "special":7,
         "coins":15000,
         "messages":754
      },
      {
         "uid":12,
         "special":7,
         "coins":15000,
         "messages":575
      }
   ]
}
```

Comment: you tried with the `length` property ? like array.length

Comment: @Namysh, yes, it worked with JSON, but it doesn't work with Mongoose

Comment: Can you explain what do want exactly??what’s your mean in mongoose?

Comment: @MohammadYaserAhmadi I need to count the number of objects in an array that is in a collection using Mongoose.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`$size`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/size/) into an aggregation pipeline to get total size of array in this way.

- `$set` is to set the filed `size` with total lenght of the array.
- `$project` is to output only `size` field.

```js
db.collection.aggregate({
  "$set": {
    "size": {
      "$size": "$users"
    }
  }
},
{
  "$project": {
    "size": 1
  }
})
```

Example [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/ba-5AtDvpAy)